# Firefox 19 : how to filter uploaded files by type?

Tags: html, firefox, web-applications, file-upload

How can I get a file upload control in Firefox to only allow .xlsx files?
I already have specified "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" as the accepted type (I'm using Rails so using the file_field_tag element).

The above filter works fine on Chrome, but doesn't seem to have any effect in Firefox.